# Handle jQuery slider when min and max are same in values

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using [link text](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider) for implementing slider in my application, but it throws exception when the min and max values are equal. How can I handle such situation, any help on it?

Thanks
Ashwani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I handle such situation, any help on it?

Validate them before specifying as widget parameters?

Comment: Lol, I can do this, but what will be the behavior of the widget?

Comment: i agree that it's unexpected widget behavior - so, why did not you create a bug at the http://dev.jquery.com/?